# How to parse CSV to object fields with different type C#?

Tags: c#

I dont see this question specifically? But how do you parse a CSV file and store it as a model when one of the fields is not of the same type because it requires a little extra logic and a conversion. See below:
**CSV rows/cols**

```
"EmployeeId,OrganizationIdList"
    "12345,987/654/321"
    "54321,123/456/789"
```

**Model**

```
public class Employee
{
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public List<long> OrganizationIdList { get; set; }
}
```

***Code I'm thinking about?***

```
   using (var stream = xxx(I get my stream using Azure))
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
   using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var employees = new List<employees>();
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Employee>().ToList();
    foreach (var record in records)
    { 
      employees.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = record.EmployeeId, OrganizationIdList = record.OrganizationIdList });
    }
}
```

Now as you and I know, OrganizationidList comes up **NULL** so how do I split and breakdown the incoming string to grab the longs? I cant figure this out? I need it to not be hard coded so the columns can switch places or the rows as I figured out how to do this by indexing. Any and all help welcomed!

**Edit**
I need to split and grab the 987/654/321 to convert(parse) into longs but how?

Answer (score 0):

parse the second column as a string then

```
    string inp ="987/654/321";
    var bits = inp.Split('/');
    var orgs = bits.Select(b=>Int32.Parse(b)).ToList();
```

you will need `using System.Linq`

Comment: So how do I grab that value specifically? I get how to break it down with the split but how do I actually parse it to grab the field and break it down? By the time it hits the variable ```records```, the value of ```OrganizationIdList == null```? Is there a better way to parse it to mapp to a model?

Comment: @LongDe you cant, you need to read it into  EmployeeTemp class (2 strings) and then convert to Employee by copy the first column and passing the second column through this code